# Send sticky intent via adb am command

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, sticky

I have command like this, but all I am missing is the intent should be sticky. How do I do this ?

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.SOME_ACTION --ei android.intent.extra.SOME_EXTRA 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you can not send sticky intent via am

Comment: Just look at am sources https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/742a67127366c376fdf188ff99ba30b27d3bf90c/cmds/am/src/com/android/commands/am/Am.java

Answer (score 0):

change **false** to **true** in here (one before the last parameter see in **bold** bellow):

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerShellCommand.java;l=805

mInterface.broadcastIntentWithFeature(null, null, intent, null, receiver, 0, null, null,
requiredPermissions, null, null, android.app.AppOpsManager.OP_NONE, bundle, true,
**false**, mUserId);

call to:

```
   public final int broadcastIntentWithFeature(IApplicationThread caller, String callingFeatureId,
            Intent intent, String resolvedType, IIntentReceiver resultTo,
            int resultCode, String resultData, Bundle resultExtras,
            String[] requiredPermissions, int appOp, Bundle bOptions,
            boolean serialized, boolean sticky, int userId)
```

then recompile with:

make services

adb root && adb remount

adb push $OUT/system/framework/services.jar /system/framework/

adb shell am reset

and now adb shell am broadcast do sticky broadcast on your android ! :)